# How do I override the ProductName property at installtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

In the setup project, I set the ProductName property to 'MyProductName'. The client wants to be able to override this value at installation time to some other value depending upon which client of theirs is installing the product. Its seems like I could set a command line value and capture this in the Install method of a Custom Action(I know how to do that). But what do I do with the value from the Command Line to get the new value to appear everywhere that ProductName proeperty does during the installation? They would also like override the Title and the AddRemovePrograms icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. ProductName is immuttable at install time.  Instead, your customers should be looking at creating [Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There's this free tool from the Windows Installer SDK called Orca that they can use.